# Spin Shortcut Key (2.8)

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

what's the spin shortcut key?  In 2.79 it was Alt-R, but it no longer works.  I looked on the user preferences, but I couldn't figure out the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The shortcut has been removed in Blender 2.8](https://developer.blender.org/T67799). There are two ways you can add a shortcut, either through the keymap or by right clicking on the tool in the toolbar.

You can add it to your keymap under *3D View > Mesh* as `mesh.spin`. However it's not particularly useful without the gizmo because the shortcut requires the configuration of the properties in the panel, which is much more time consuming.

[image]

The other approach is to right click on the spin tool in the toolbar, select *Assign Shortcut* and press the key combination that shall later trigger the tool. When you create the shortcut using this approach it will show the gizmo. This shortcut can also be created manually in the keymap (*3D View > Mesh*) by setting the identifier to `wm.tool_set_by_id` and the identifier of the tool to `builtin.spin`.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.  I figured out that by right-clicking on the spin button on the tool bar, you can add a shortcut key.

Comment: @RBlong2us yes that also works.

Comment: is there any difference by which method you use?  I'm asking for a reason which is rather hard to explain

Comment: @RBlong2us Interesting, it does make a difference, because that way it actually shows the gizmo.

Comment: I'm not sure I like that.  I would prefer that it would automatically spin to an amount that I have used berore, then I can edit it later, instead of me having to drag it.  That's how it worked in 2.79..  I'm fine with it though.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got your result.  I tried to add a shortcut, but nothing happened when I tried it out.

Comment: I'm sure the shortcut worked, but as you said, the widget doesn't appear.  Where are the settings, then?  Am I missing something?

Comment: It should appear in the bottom left corner.

Comment: hmm... mustve done something wrong.  I did add a shortcut, though

Comment: oh, well.  It's not worth hassling over.  Thanks for your time, and for the overall summary.  Your answer probably works, I just must be messing up somewhere or something. :)

Comment: @RBlong2us added screenshots for the keymap configuration. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @rjg.  I've now got a solution that satisfies me.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do they have this obsession of moving shortcuts around? It really doesn't help anyone except to waste their time.

Comment: @Sebi 2.8x was a major update to Blender, with lots of new functionality that also required adjustments to the keymap.

Comment: @RobertGutzow Thanks! But it does make it hell to follow 2.7x tutorials :(